# put a Calendar Entry with Backlink to an app

Tags: android, hyperlink, calendar, intentfilter

Inside our App there is a "add Calendar entry" function, that opens a Calendar-Entry-Edit-Activity. I'll like to put a link inside the Message, that the user can click to come back to our App with additional Informations. 
Inside the Manifest we have the following Intent-filter Entry:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" / >
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="our.namespace.de" android:path="/search" />
</intent-filter>
```

to put a link inside like this:

`http://our.namespace.de/search/some_infos`

A click on it triggers an Activity-chooser, and every browser is showing up inside that list. How to create a link, only our App listens to? The problem here is that any other type than html will not get recognized as link inside the Calendar-TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should be `android:pathPrefix` if you are trying to match the URL you link to.

Regardless, one downside of the `http://` approach for launching apps is that it will bring up all browsers in addition to your app.

You can attempt to use `Intent` and [`toUri()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toUri%28int%29) to create a representation of an arbitrary `Intent`, and use that as a link target.

Comment: tried your Intent.toUri() which works well inside custom TextViews, but doesn't on the Calendar (I guess it only highlightes http:// urls).

Comment: @RafaelT: Ah, yeah, good point. The `Linkify` logic in there won't recognize the `intent` scheme. Sorry!